# ESP32-CAM how to publish large binary payload to AWS IOT ssl mqtt topic, tested many libs without success :-(

Tags: ssl, mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, platformio

I'm currently working on an ESP32CAM project to publish on AWS IOT topic some captures from the camera in high resolution (UXGA).
I've managed to publish some short json payloads with attributes to different AWS IOT certificate protected topics but I'm facing an annoying issue to do the same with large payload as the capture binary file.

I've browsed many sites, forums, tested differents libs like MQTT, PubSubClient, AsyncMQTTClient... but **I've not found a true working solution** for **large payload** around 100KB size.

For example with the PubSubClient lib, I try to fragment my binary payload with the BeginPublish, write, endPublish scheme as below :

```
bool publishBinary(const uint8_t *buffer,size_t len, const char *topicPubName)
{
  Serial.print("publishing binary ["+(String)len+"] ...");
  if (len == 0) {
    // Empty file
    Serial.println("Error : binary payload is empty!");
    return(false);
  }

  if (!client.beginPublish(topicPubName,len,false)) {
    Serial.println("MQTT beginPublish failed.");
    return(false);
  }
  size_t max_transfer_size=80;
  size_t n=0;
  size_t size_send;
  size_t offset=0;

  while ((len-offset)>0) {
    n=(len-offset);
    if (n > max_transfer_size)
      n=max_transfer_size;

    size_send=client.write((const uint8_t *)(buffer+offset),n);
    Serial.printf("%d/%d : %.02f %%\n",offset,len,(double)((100*offset)/len));
    //Serial.println("n: "+(String)n+" - send: "+(String)size_send);
    if(size_send != n) { 
      // error handling. this is triggered on write fail.
      Serial.println("Error during publishing..."+(String)size_send+" instead of "+(String)n);
      client.endPublish();
      return(false);
    } else {
      offset+=size_send;
    }
  }
  client.endPublish();
  Serial.println("ok");

  return(true);
}
```

client is defined as **PubSubClient client(net)** where net is WiFiClientSecure object with validated CA_cert, cert and private key.

The MQTT connection is working well but when I try to publish the large binary payload, the function fragments buffer into chunks till the end but there is quite always an error like **UNKNOWN ERROR CODE (0050)** or when it succeeds to publish, only a small part of payload is published on the destination. In this case, my jpeg file is truncated on my S3 bucket where the payload lands.

I have to say that sometimes, I managed to publish a 65K payload but like a stroke of luck... :-)

I've looked for some examples on the web but very often it is for small payload. As mentioned in a post, I've tested the Publish_P(...) from PubSubClient... but same result, it aborts during transfer.

I begin to ask myself if it really possible by mqtt topic or do I have to create an API gateway with a lambda to handle such large payload. Tell me I'm wrong :-)

If you know a good solution for a true working large payload publishing, I would be delighted to discuss with you :-)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
void setup() {
...
  boolean res = mqttClient.setBufferSize(50*1024); // ok for 640*480
  if (res) Serial.println("Buffer resized."); else Serial.println("Buffer resizing failed");
...
}
```

I'm working with 50kB buffer and it works well, haven't tried beyond that bu it should work with 100kB as well.

After you've resized the buffer publish as you normally would.

BTW, setBufferSize function was only recently added IIRC.

Comment: thanks, Davor !!! you saved me lot . After 1 month of struggle, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had problems with the PubSubClient library and large files too. In the end I figured out, that I have to update the PubSubClient.h as follows:

```
//128000 = 128 kB is the maximum size for AWS I think..
#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 100000 

// It takes a long time to transmit the large files 
// maybe even more than 200 seconds...
#define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 200
#define MQTT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT 200
```

Comment: Thanks Frederik, I will give a try but this long duration for uploading a 100K payload could be problematic. I'm working on parallel on a more classic HTTPS API with PUT method on AWS to speed up and securise such upload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found that PubSubClient's `bufferSize` is defined as `uint16_t`.

https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/v2.8/src/PubSubClient.h#L92

So, we can't extend the buffer size over 64 kB, and can't publish a large payload.

[Michael's comment](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/issues/791#issuecomment-800096719) might help you.

Comment: Hello! I highly recommend you to post the referenced Michael's comment into your answer, as this can be deleted in the future. By this way, we can keep your answer helping people even in the future. :)